# parametrización de Script para monitoreo de servidor en linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

He encontrado unos scripts en la web para monitorear una matriz de almacenamiento MD3200, pero no comprendo que argumentos pasar en algunas líneas. Anexo evidencias del script.
Hay un archivo de configuración que establece las siguientes variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y unos scripts que usan este archivo. Sin embargo, en estos scripts hay unas variables que no sé que parámetro pasar, dejo la siguiente evidencia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las variables a las que me refiero son $1 y $2 en la línea 3 y 8.
A continuación delo el repositorio de los scripts encontrados: https://github.com/everythings-gonna-be-alright/zabbix-dell-md3200-smcli
Soy nuevo en esto y espero me ayuden. Gracias.

Comment: Hola CHAD, bienvenido,  la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edítala, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, la pregunta es sobre `bash`, no sobre `python` (los 2 scripts a los que haces referencia usan `bash`).

Answer (score 2):

`$1` y `$2` en bash serían 2 de los argumentos que se pasan al llamar al script... digamos que llamas al script así:

```
./el-script.sh estos son algunos argumentos para un ejemplo sencillo
```

`$1` sería `estos` y `$2` sería `son`. Veo que el script también usa `$0`. `$0` es el script en sí, como quiera que fue llamado, no su ruta completa... es decir, en la llamada que yo hice como ejemplo, `$0` sería `./el-script.sh`.

`man bash` tiene toda una sección sobre parámetros.